# Checking if UDP port is open in autoIT

Tags: udp, connection, port, autoit, port-scanning

I am working on a program for TCP/UDP port scanning. TCP is working fine and well but it seems like I have no idea on how to achieve the UDP port scanning using the AutoIt.

Since the UDP port is connectionless I am using  `UDPOpen` function to bind my `$PortIP` and `$PortStartNumberB`. Unfortunately when I scan it will list out all ports. By now it will show up the respective open port for UDP for example 4008 (since i testing using advance port scanner tool and only this port should be be open).

Could someone more knowledgeable than myself please help me to understand on 
how I can modify the function code posted below since I am not able to reproduce the UDP open port list in AutoIt script? Platform is Win7 x86.

```
$portList = "  "
$PortIP = "192.168.11.1"
$PortEndNumberB = "4010"
$PortStartNumberB = "4000"

Func ScanUDP()
    UDPStartup()
    $timerstart = TimerInit()

    For $LetsGo = $PortStartNumberB To $PortEndNumberB
        $a = UDPOpen($PortIP, $PortStartNumberB, 1)
        If @error <> 0 Then
            $portList = $portList & $PortStartNumberB & @CRLF
        EndIf

        $PortStartNumberB = $PortStartNumberB + 1
    Next

    UDPShutdown()
    $timerend = TimerDiff($timerstart)
    TrayTip("Port Scanner", "Done Process took " & Round($timerend,-1)/1000 & " seconds", 7, 1)
EndFunc
```

What I have tried:

when i try run, it list out all the port from.

4000
4001
4002
4003
4004
4005
4006
4007
4008
4009
4010

by right, i need to display only 4008 which is the right open udp port (i has tested using other freeware tools-advance port scan)

Comment: Define 'open port'. Do you mean open in the firewall, or open in the sense of a local application listening to it?

Comment: Hi @EJP.. thanks for your reply..it was my local application which are being set to open only 4008.  I already disable the firewall to make it no sense. but it seems like failure if i try to checking the UDP port-4008 creating using autoIT script, does my script logic is correct? thanks again.

Comment: I have no idea, until you answer my question.

Comment: as for my understanding, 'open port' can be define as there are port are listen to. so in my case, the local application has allowed the 4008 UDP to be open. so i just need to prove that the port is listening to 4008.

Comment: Hi SF, are you wanting to check if UDP port 4008 is open on the local machine? Or a remote machine?

Comment: hi @Fidel . it is on my other local machine that i connected using USB.i need to scan that port to ensure all ports are closed but actually in that machine it has been setup to purposely to open the 4008 port. so now, my script on autoIT is not sufficient to check properly on the UDP port. Do you have any ideas to share with me? thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Thanks SF. Btw your for-loop was a bit broken. I've fixed it up in my answer below. I hope you find it helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of seeing open UDP ports is to use the following command:

```
netstat -an -p UDP
```

It would be possible to scrape the output of that command using AutoIt, however the better way is to use the API provided by Microsoft. Specifically the [GetUdpTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366033(v=vs.85).aspx) and [GetExtendedUdpTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365930(v=vs.85).aspx) functions.

Thankfully a kind person called zampoot has already [written wrappers](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/155368-close-tcpudp-connection-by-process-name-without-killing-the-process/) for those calls. I was able to take his script and modify it to suit your purpose.

Just look at the main method and don't worry too much about the rest. If you're adventurous, re-instate the `_ArrayDisplay($aUDPArray)` line - it will show you a lot more about which processes are using the open ports.

Here is the code:

```
#include <Array.au3>

Global Const $hIPHLPAPI = DllOpen("iphlpapi.dll")
Global Const $hWTSAPI32 = DllOpen("wtsapi32.dll")
Global Const $hKERNEL32 = DllOpen("kernel32.dll")
Global Const $hPSAPI = DllOpen("psapi.dll")
Global Const $hNTDLL = DllOpen("ntdll.dll")
Global Const $hWS232 = DllOpen("ws2_32.dll")
Global Const $hADVAPI32 = DllOpen("advapi32.dll")
Global Const $sSystemModule = _CV_SystemModuleInformation()
Global $iIsAdmin = IsAdmin()

$portList = "  "
$PortIP = "192.168.11.1"
$PortEndNumberB = "4010"
$PortStartNumberB = "4000"

main()

Func main()
    $aUDPArray = _CV_GetExtendedUdpTable()
    ;_ArrayDisplay($aUDPArray)

    $ports = _GetUDPPorts($PortIP)
    ;_ArrayDisplay($ports)

    $timerstart = TimerInit()

    $portList = ""
    For $port = $PortStartNumberB To $PortEndNumberB

        $index = _ArraySearch($ports, $port)

        If ($index > -1) Then
            ;port found

            If StringLen($portList) > 0 Then
                $portList &= @CRLF
            EndIf

            $portList &= $port
        EndIf
    Next

    ConsoleWrite($portList)

    $timerend = TimerDiff($timerstart)
    TrayTip("Port Scanner", "Done Process took " & Round($timerend, -1) / 1000 & " seconds", 7, 1)

EndFunc   ;==>main

Func _GetUDPPorts($ipOfInterest)
    $aUDPArray = _CV_GetExtendedUdpTable()

    Dim $ports[1]
    $ports[0] = "Port"

    For $rowNum = 1 To UBound($aUDPArray) - 1
        $ip = $aUDPArray[$rowNum][1]
        $port = $aUDPArray[$rowNum][2]

        ;only get the ports for the ip of interest
        If ($ipOfInterest = $ip) Then

            ;check if this port already exists in our list
            $pos = _ArraySearch($ports, $port)

            If $pos = -1 Then
                _ArrayAdd($ports, $port)
            EndIf
        EndIf
    Next
    _ArrayDelete($ports, 0)

    Return $ports

EndFunc   ;==>_GetUDPPorts

Func _CV_GetExtendedUdpTable()

    Local $aCall = DllCall($hIPHLPAPI, "dword", "GetExtendedUdpTable", _
            "ptr*", 0, _
            "dword*", 0, _
            "int", 1, _ ; 1, sort in ascending order
            "dword", 2, _ ; AF_INET4
            "dword", 1, _ ; UDP_TABLE_OWNER_PID
            "dword", 0)

    If @error Then
        Return SetError(1, 0, 0)
    EndIf

    If $aCall[0] <> 122 Then ; ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER
        Return SetError(2, 0, 0)
    EndIf

    Local $iSize = $aCall[2]

    Local $tByteStructure = DllStructCreate("byte[" & $iSize & "]")

    $aCall = DllCall($hIPHLPAPI, "dword", "GetExtendedUdpTable", _
            "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($tByteStructure), _
            "dword*", $iSize, _
            "int", 1, _ ; 1, sort in ascending order
            "dword", 2, _ ; AF_INET4
            "dword", 1, _ ; UDP_TABLE_OWNER_PID
            "dword", 0)

    If @error Or $aCall[0] Then
        Return SetError(3, 0, 0)
    EndIf

    Local $tMIB_UDPTABLE_OWNER_PID_DWORDS = DllStructCreate("dword[" & Ceiling($iSize / 4) & "]", DllStructGetPtr($tByteStructure))

    Local $iUDPentries = DllStructGetData($tMIB_UDPTABLE_OWNER_PID_DWORDS, 1)

    #cs
        $tMIB_UDPROW_OWNER_PID = DllStructCreate("dword LocalAddr;" & _
        "dword LocalPort;" & _
        "dword OwningPid")
    #ce

    Local $aUDPTable[$iUDPentries + 1][6] = [["Process Name            ", "Local IP                  ", "Local Port", "PID", "Full Path", "User Name"]]

    Local $aProcesses = _CV_ProcessList()

    Local $iOffset
    Local $iIP

    UDPStartup()

    For $i = 1 To $iUDPentries

        $iOffset = ($i - 1) * 3 + 1 ; going thru array of dwords

        $iIP = DllStructGetData($tMIB_UDPTABLE_OWNER_PID_DWORDS, 1, $iOffset + 1)

        If $iIP = 16777343 Then
            $aUDPTable[$i][1] = "127.0.0.1"
        ElseIf $iIP = 0 Then
            $aUDPTable[$i][1] = "Any local address"
        Else
            $aUDPTable[$i][1] = BitOR(BinaryMid($iIP, 1, 1), 0) & "." & BitOR(BinaryMid($iIP, 2, 1), 0) & "." & BitOR(BinaryMid($iIP, 3, 1), 0) & "." & BitOR(BinaryMid($iIP, 4, 1), 0)
            $aUDPTable[$i][1] = $aUDPTable[$i][1]
        EndIf

        $aUDPTable[$i][2] = Dec(Hex(BinaryMid(DllStructGetData($tMIB_UDPTABLE_OWNER_PID_DWORDS, 1, $iOffset + 2), 1, 2)))
        $aUDPTable[$i][2] &= "" ;_CV_GetPortHint($aUDPTable[$i][2])

        $aUDPTable[$i][3] = DllStructGetData($tMIB_UDPTABLE_OWNER_PID_DWORDS, 1, $iOffset + 3)
        If Not $aUDPTable[$i][3] Then
            $aUDPTable[$i][3] = "-"
            $aUDPTable[$i][0] = "System Idle Process"
            $aUDPTable[$i][4] = "-"
            $aUDPTable[$i][5] = "SYSTEM"
        Else
            For $j = 1 To $aProcesses[0][0]
                If $aProcesses[$j][1] = $aUDPTable[$i][3] Then
                    $aUDPTable[$i][0] = $aProcesses[$j][0]
                    $aUDPTable[$i][4] = _CV_GetPIDFileName($aProcesses[$j][1])
                    If Not $aUDPTable[$i][4] Then
                        If $aUDPTable[$i][0] = $sSystemModule Then
                            $aUDPTable[$i][4] = @SystemDir & "\" & $sSystemModule
                        Else
                            $aUDPTable[$i][4] = "-"
                        EndIf
                    EndIf
                    If Not $aUDPTable[$i][0] Then $aUDPTable[$i][0] = $aProcesses[$j][0]
                    $aUDPTable[$i][5] = $aProcesses[$j][2]
                    If Not $aUDPTable[$i][5] Then
                        If $iIsAdmin Then
                            $aUDPTable[$i][5] = "SYSTEM"
                        Else
                            $aUDPTable[$i][5] = "-"
                        EndIf
                    EndIf
                    ExitLoop
                EndIf
            Next
        EndIf

    Next

    UDPShutdown()

    Return $aUDPTable

EndFunc   ;==>_CV_GetExtendedUdpTable

Func _CV_PtrStringLen($pString)
    Local $aCall = DllCall($hKERNEL32, "dword", "lstrlen", "ptr", $pString)
    If @error Then Return SetError(1, 0, 0)
    Return $aCall[0]
EndFunc   ;==>_CV_PtrStringLen

Func _CV_PtrStringLenW($pString)
    Local $aCall = DllCall($hKERNEL32, "dword", "lstrlenW", "ptr", $pString)
    If @error Then Return SetError(1, 0, 0)
    Return $aCall[0]
EndFunc   ;==>_CV_PtrStringLenW

Func _CV_ProcessList()
    Local $aCall = DllCall($hWTSAPI32, "bool", "WTSEnumerateProcessesW", _
            "handle", 0, _
            "dword", 0, _
            "dword", 1, _
            "ptr*", 0, _
            "dword*", 0)
    If @error Or Not $aCall[0] Then
        Local $aProcesses = ProcessList()
        ReDim $aProcesses[$aProcesses[0][0]][3]
        For $i = 1 To UBound($aProcesses) - 1
            $aProcesses[$i][2] = "-"
        Next
        Return SetError(1, 0, $aProcesses)
    EndIf
    Local $tWTS_PROCESS_INFO
    Local $pString, $iStringLen
    Local $aOut[$aCall[5] + 1][3]
    $aOut[0][0] = $aCall[5]
    For $i = 1 To $aCall[5]
        $tWTS_PROCESS_INFO = DllStructCreate("dword SessionId;" & _
                "dword ProcessId;" & _
                "ptr ProcessName;" & _
                "ptr UserSid", _
                $aCall[4] + ($i - 1) * DllStructGetSize($tWTS_PROCESS_INFO)) ; looping thru structures
        $pString = DllStructGetData($tWTS_PROCESS_INFO, "ProcessName")
        $iStringLen = _CV_PtrStringLenW($pString)
        $aOut[$i][0] = DllStructGetData(DllStructCreate("wchar[" & $iStringLen + 1 & "]", $pString), 1)
        If $aOut[$i][0] = "System" Then $aOut[$i][0] = $sSystemModule ; & " (System)"
        $aOut[$i][1] = DllStructGetData($tWTS_PROCESS_INFO, "ProcessId")
        $aOut[$i][2] = _CV_AccountName(DllStructGetData($tWTS_PROCESS_INFO, "UserSid"))
    Next
    DllCall($hWTSAPI32, "none", "WTSFreeMemory", "ptr", $aCall[4])
    Return $aOut
EndFunc   ;==>_CV_ProcessList

Func _CV_SystemModuleInformation()
    Local $aCall = DllCall($hNTDLL, "long", "NtQuerySystemInformation", _
            "dword", 11, _ ; SystemModuleInformation
            "ptr", 0, _
            "dword", 0, _
            "dword*", 0)
    If @error Then Return SetError(1, 0, "")
    Local $iSize = $aCall[4]
    Local $tBufferRaw = DllStructCreate("byte[" & $iSize & "]")
    Local $pBuffer = DllStructGetPtr($tBufferRaw)
    $aCall = DllCall($hNTDLL, "long", "NtQuerySystemInformation", _
            "dword", 11, _ ; SystemModuleInformation
            "ptr", $pBuffer, _
            "dword", $iSize, _
            "dword*", 0)
    If @error Then Return SetError(2, 0, "")
    Local $pPointer = $pBuffer
    Local $tSYSTEM_MODULE_Modified = DllStructCreate("dword_ptr ModulesCount;" & _
            "dword_ptr Reserved[2];" & _
            "ptr ImageBaseAddress;" & _
            "dword ImageSize;" & _
            "dword Flags;" & _
            "word Index;" & _
            "word Unknown;" & _
            "word LoadCount;" & _
            "word ModuleNameOffset;" & _
            "char ImageName[256]", _
            $pPointer)
    Local $iNameOffset = DllStructGetData($tSYSTEM_MODULE_Modified, "ModuleNameOffset")
    Local $sImageName = DllStructGetData($tSYSTEM_MODULE_Modified, "ImageName")
    Return StringTrimLeft($sImageName, $iNameOffset)
EndFunc   ;==>_CV_SystemModuleInformation

Func _CV_IpToName($iIP)
    Return $iIP
    Local $aCall = DllCall($hWS232, "ptr", "gethostbyaddr", _
            "dword*", $iIP, _
            "int", 4, _
            "int", 2) ; AF_INET
    If @error Or Not $aCall[0] Then Return SetError(1, 0, "")
    Local $pHostent = $aCall[0]
    Local $tHostent = DllStructCreate("align 2; ptr Name;" & _
            "ptr Aliases;" & _
            "ushort Addrtype;" & _
            "ushort Length;" & _
            "ptr AddrList", _
            $pHostent)
    Return DllStructGetData(DllStructCreate("char[" & _CV_PtrStringLen(DllStructGetData($tHostent, "Name")) + 1 & "]", DllStructGetData($tHostent, "Name")), 1)
EndFunc   ;==>_CV_IpToName

Func _CV_GetPIDFileName($iPID)
    Local $aCall = DllCall($hKERNEL32, "ptr", "OpenProcess", _
            "dword", 1040, _ ; PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_READ
            "int", 0, _
            "dword", $iPID)
    If @error Or Not $aCall[0] Then Return SetError(1, 0, "")
    Local $hProcess = $aCall[0]
    $aCall = DllCall($hPSAPI, "dword", "GetModuleFileNameExW", _
            "handle", $hProcess, _
            "ptr", 0, _
            "wstr", "", _
            "dword", 32767)
    If @error Or Not $aCall[0] Then
        DllCall($hKERNEL32, "bool", "CloseHandle", "handle", $hProcess)
        Return SetError(2, 0, "")
    EndIf
    Local $sFilename = $aCall[3]
    DllCall($hKERNEL32, "bool", "CloseHandle", "handle", $hProcess)
    Return $sFilename
EndFunc   ;==>_CV_GetPIDFileName

Func _CV_AccountName($pSID)
    Local $aCall = DllCall($hADVAPI32, "bool", "LookupAccountSidW", _
            "ptr", 0, _
            "ptr", $pSID, _
            "wstr", "", _
            "dword*", 1024, _
            "wstr", "", _
            "dword*", 1024, _
            "ptr*", 0)
    If @error Or Not $aCall[0] Then Return SetError(1, 0, "")
    Return $aCall[3]
EndFunc   ;==>_CV_AccountName
```